# How can I delete my own comments from mobile phone

Tags: support, status-bydesign, mobile-site

I did search for this but could not find any answers on Arqade Meta. Did not search MSO. But is it possible to be able to delete my own comments from mobile browser?

In mobile version of Arqade, I see my comment, and my name. But there is no little icon next to my name to enable comment deletion. I am using Android on a Galaxy S2 with the default browser (do not know the name) if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile site only offers a limited subset of features to make those that make the cut more useful on mobile devices where no precision pointing device (fancy term for the "mouse") is available.

Comment deletion or editing is not one of the features that made the cut, sorry.

Comment: There is, however, an option at the bottom of the page to view the "Full Site" in place of the mobile site. You should be able to edit or remove comments from there.

Comment: @desaivv The footer has the link to go back to mobile :)